# link shenanigans?

Tags: html, hyperlink, whitelist

If using an HTML whitelist and HTMLPurifier, are there any ***shenanigans*** a malicious user can execute if `<a></a>` is allowed?

For atmosphere:

[image: Shenanigans!]

Comment: Not really sure why I'm getting downvoted. It's a legitimate question. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you only allow the `href` attribute and don't allow the `javascript:` pseudo protocol.